# How to pipe a stream using pdfkit with node js

Tags: node.js, node-pdfkit

Before PDFkit 0.5 - the following worked for me (generating a pdf via pdfkit/printing via ipp to CUPS):

```
var ipp = require("ipp");
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.text("Hello World");

doc.output(function(pdf)){
    var printer = ipp.Printer("http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/1");
    var file = {
        "operation-attributes-tag":{
            "requesting-user-name": "User",
        "job-name": "Print Job",
        "document-format": "application/pdf"
        },
        data: new Buffer(pdf, "binary")
    };

    printer.execute("Print-Job", file, function (err, res) {
        console.log("Printed: "+res.statusCode);
    });
}
```

As of PDFkit 0.5 - the `output` method is deprecated - but I can't seem to find an example of using the new `pipe` method with my scenario. If I'm not using a browser, do I still need a module like [blob-stream](https://github.com/devongovett/blob-stream)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since pdfkit PDFDocument now is a stream, you have to buffer the data coming from the buffer:

```
var ipp = require("ipp");
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.text("Hello World");

var buffers = [];
doc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
doc.on('end', function () {
    var printer = ipp.Printer("http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/1");
    var file = {
        "operation-attributes-tag":{
            "requesting-user-name": "User",
        "job-name": "Print Job",
        "document-format": "application/pdf"
        },
        data: Buffer.concat(buffers)
    };

    printer.execute("Print-Job", file, function (err, res) {
        console.log("Printed: "+res.statusCode);
    });
});
doc.end();
```

Or you can use something like [concat-stream](https://github.com/maxogden/concat-stream) module:

```
var ipp = require("ipp");
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
var concat = require("concat-stream");

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.text("Hello World");

doc.pipe(concat(function (data) {
    var printer = ipp.Printer("http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/1");
    var file = {
        "operation-attributes-tag":{
            "requesting-user-name": "User",
        "job-name": "Print Job",
        "document-format": "application/pdf"
        },
        data: data
    };

    printer.execute("Print-Job", file, function (err, res) {
        console.log("Printed: "+res.statusCode);
    });
}));
doc.end();
```

Comment: This works for me as well. Be sure to call `doc.end()` to actually fire off the end event. I've added an edit for anyone that comes across this new to the library.

Comment: Hi there! I would like to use that suggestion in my code. Unfortunately, I've a problem: when I try to save the binary data performing  fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', buffers) to get its content back, it generates a corrupted file.  @Josiah some suggestion?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Yeah, you can concatenate the buffers into one buffer and only then you can pass it to fs.writeFileSync: `fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', Buffer.concat(buffers))`. Of course to do it properly you should be streaming to it and you wouldn't need buffering: `doc.pipe (fs.createWriteStream('test.pdf'))`

Comment: This was really helpful using `doc.on('end')`. Spent 4 hours trying to get this working and your solution fixed it. Saves me creating a temp file to upload elsewhere, whereas now I can just send Buffer directly.