# S3 and Couchbase - How get a file from Amazon and store it?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, couchbase

I'm trying to get a file from S3, and store it in NoSQL Couchbase.

I'm trying to store the outputStream, with the following code:

```
        var outputStream1 = fs.createWriteStream("./tmp/" + url);
        // if statusCode == 200, then we have the file, lets save it in out cache and then send it to the client
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            outputStream1.write(chunk);
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            var value = outputStream1;
            cb.set(key, value, function (err, result) {
                if (err) { console.log(err); }
                console.log("Set item for key with CAS: " + result.cas);
                cb.get(key, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) { console.log(err); }
                    console.log("Value for key is: " + result.value);
                    var readStream = result.value;
                    readStream.on('open', function () {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                    readStream.on('end', function () {
                        readStream.close();
                    });
                });
            });
```

The problem is that I store the outputStream, and then trying to read it.

I search for a way to store the data object we get from S3 in Couchbase, and then have the ability to send it to the client. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set a Buffer as value and get that later. First you need to save the data in a buffer:

```
    var buffers = [];
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        buffers.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        var value = Buffer.concat(buffers);
        cb.set(key, value, function (err, result) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            console.log("Set item for key with CAS: " + result.cas);
            cb.get(key, function (err, result) {
                if (err) { console.log(err); }
                console.log("Value for key is: " + result.value); // You should get your value in here              });
        });
```

You can also use [concat-stream](https://github.com/maxogden/concat-stream) module to help you. [I've answered a similar question on buffering stream.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23780269/774086)